# React-route-dom NavLink with SemanticUI not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having a grand old hard time trying to implement this. I already searched everywhere for the solution, but could not make it work.

I have my routes defined in a separate file called routes.jsx,

[image]

on my app, I am importing my Routes and my Navigation, and this part is okay

[image]

but my issue is with, the Navigation, When I click, home or about for instance, the browser take me there, but the content of the body does not update, so for instance, when I click on the nav link about, I don't see about in the body, I have to refresh the browser to see it...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post code snippets instead of pictures of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are using two separate `<BrowserRouter>`s. It should go on the highest level of your component hierarchy. I would remove it from `Routes` and `Nav` and start `<App>` with it

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
   return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        ....
      </BrowserRouter>
   ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, If I remove the BrowserRouter from the Nav, I actually get another error... Uncaught Error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() ...That's why I added.

Comment: As I say, your <App /> component should wrap everything in BrowserRouter. It travels through the context